# GGplot - R - Second Axis on Color / Group - Long Format

Tags: r, ggplot2

unfortunately i struggel with the GGPlot and the secondary axis.
I created a long format of data with three categories i want to display in a GGplot.
1 should be displayed as a multiplot,
1 is the color
1 is the line type. like here in the chart!

[image]

The Problem i have now is, that i am not aware how to integrate a secondary axis for the "dotted lines" for example. Alternative i could just flip the data and include the second axis for the color, but i assume this is the very same problem.
Thanks in advance!

this is the code i have so far.

```
#test 
cat1 <- c(rep("A",10),rep("B",10),rep("A",10),rep("B",10),rep("A",10),rep("B",10),rep("A",10),rep("B",10))
cat2 <- c(rep("A",10),rep("B",10),rep("B",10),rep("A",10),rep("A",10),rep("B",10),rep("B",10),rep("A",10))
steps <- c(seq(1,10),seq(1,10),seq(1,10),seq(1,10),seq(1,10),seq(1,10),seq(1,10),seq(1,10))
sz <- c(rep(1,40),rep(2,40))
data <- c(cumsum(exp(rnorm(10))),(rnorm(10))/100,cumsum(exp(rnorm(10))),(rnorm(10))/100,cumsum(exp(rnorm(10))),(rnorm(10))/100,cumsum(exp(rnorm(10))),(rnorm(10))/100)

df <- data.frame("Category1" = cat1,
                 "Category2" =cat2,
                 "Steps" = steps,
                 "Szenario" = sz,
                 "Value" = data)


ggplot(df,aes(x=Steps,y=Value,group=interaction(Category1,Category2),color=Category2,linetype=Category1))+
  geom_line()+
  facet_wrap(facets=vars(Szenario),scales="free")
```

Answer (score 0):

UPdate:

```
df1 <- df %>% 
  mutate(Value = ifelse(Category1=="B", Value*100, Value))
ggplot(df1,aes(x=Steps,y=Value,group=interaction(Category1,Category2),color=Category2,linetype=Category1))+
  geom_line()+
  facet_wrap(facets=vars(Szenario),scales="free") +
  scale_y_continuous("Category1",
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~ . * (min(df$Value)/max(df$Value)),
                                         name = 'Category2'))
```

[image]

You could `scale_y_continuous`:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=Steps,y=Value,group=interaction(Category1,Category2),color=Category2,linetype=Category1))+
  geom_line()+
  facet_wrap(~Szenario, scales = "free_y") +
  scale_y_continuous("Category1",
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~ . * (min(df$Value) / max(df$Value)),
                                         name = 'Category2'))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick reply, 

i would need to manipulate the dataset before and multiply the values for the category?

Comment: The multiplication is setting the proportion of the secondary axis where you multiply by `(min(df$Value) / max(df$Value))`. You don't need to manipulate the dataset. You just multiply by the factor minimum of value divded by maximum of value.

Comment: Hi TarJae, thanks for your quick reply. The Axis is multiplied correctly, but i would need to lift the data itself upwards. 
I have updated the Topic because 1 category is just a complete different scale.